# Does the chaining of multiple then on a Promise mean that multiple steps will be executed once the Promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, bluebird

I'm reading up on `bluebird` and what problems it solves for the native `Promise` API and currently learning and I keep seeing this pattern with them:

```
Promise.promisifyAll(needle);
var options = {};

var current = Promise.resolve();
Promise.map(URLs, function (URL) {
    current = current.then(function () {
        return needle.getAsync(URL, options);
    });
    return current;
}).map(function (responseAndBody) {
    return JSON.parse(responseAndBody[1]);
}).then(function (results) {
    return processAndSaveAllInDB(results);
}).then(function () {
    console.log('All Needle requests saved');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Does this all mean that once the `map` is done (which is weird because `map` doesn't return a Promise but I guess that's another question), it'll execute 2 `then` with the second waiting for the first one to complete?

Comment: Promise.map returns a Promise. You can read the bluebird API on it. The rest is all standard Promise.

Comment: @EJ2015 I see, but this is a common pattern in Promises alone.

Comment: Yes once you realize `map` returns a promise, this is just standard promise chaining

Comment: @EJ2015 Got it, but that's my question exactly. Is the usage of multiple `.then` just a "do N things after promise is resolved"?

Comment: Yes that's wight. Just to help make it clear, `then` is like the old callback. Once the current operation is done, the return value is passed to the next `then`. This means the next `then` will wait for the previous to resolve first before executing. Using `promise` and `then` makes it more readable and avoid callback hell. This part is the standard Promise in JS. You don't need to look at bluebird to understand them. Bluebird is a package with enhanced support to it. `Promise.map` is from bluebird API.